# What will happen if pthread_cond_wait() competes with another thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Here is a program bellow and its function is counting words in two files with 3 threads(one is the main thread, one for file1, and one for file2).

I know that `pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock)` will lock the mutex before it returns. But what will happen if another thread locks the mutex first?

In this program:

1. main thread calls `pthread_cond_wait`, it unlocks the mutex.
2. thread1 locks the mutex, after doing something, it calls `pthread_cond_signal`.
3. main thread got the signal sent by thread1, then it wants to lock the mutex, but the mutex was lock by thread1, so the main thread is blocked.
4. thread1 unlocks the mutex.
5. main thread(`pthread_cond_wait`) now can lock the mutex and return.

But! At this moment(**step 5**), what will happen if another thread, say thread2, locks the mutex first before `pthread_cond_wait` locks the mutex? The main thread is still blocked? If it does, then 
 this program is a buggy program, all the threads(main thread and thread2) will be blocked. But I have run it a lot of times, it worked fine.

---

**Update My Question**: Will other threads lock the mutex during the period between the moment that `pthread_cond_wait` gets the signal sent by `pthread_cond_signal` requiring the mutex to lock and the moment that `pthread_cond_wait` locks the mutex.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct arg_set {            /* two values int one arg */
    char    *filename;      /* file to examine */
    int     count;          /* number of words */
    int     code;
};

struct arg_set  *mailbox = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  flag = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *count_words(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;               /* two threads */
    struct arg_set args1, args2;    /* two argsets */
    int reports_int = 0;
    int total_words = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file1 file2", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    args1.filename  = argv[1];
    args1.count     = 0;
    args1.code      = 1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, count_words, (void *)&args1);

    args2.filename  = argv[2];
    args2.count     = 0;
    args2.code      = 2;
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, count_words, (void *)&args2);

    while (reports_int < 2) {
        printf("MAIN: waiting for flag to go up\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock);
        printf("MAIN: Wow! flag was raised, I have the lock\n");
        printf("%7d: %s\n", mailbox->count, mailbox->filename);
        total_words += mailbox->count;
        if (mailbox == &args1)
            pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        if (mailbox == &args2)
            pthread_join(t2, NULL);
        mailbox = NULL;
        pthread_cond_signal(&flag);
        reports_int++;
    }

    printf("%7d: total words\n", total_words);

    return 0;
}

void *count_words(void *a)
{
    struct arg_set *args = a;
    FILE *fp;
    int c, prevc = '\0';

    if ((fp = fopen(args->filename, "r")) != NULL) {
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if (!isalnum(c) && isalnum(prevc))
                args->count++;
            prevc = c;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else
        perror(args->filename);

    printf("COUNT %d: waiting to get lock\n", args->code);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("COUNT %d: have lock, storing data\n", args->code);
    if (mailbox != NULL)
        pthread_cond_wait(&flag, &lock);
    mailbox = args;
    printf("COUNT %d: raising flag\n", args->code);
    pthread_cond_signal(&flag);
    printf("COUNT %d: unlocking box\n", args->code);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Without further analysis: "I have run it a lot of times, it worked fine" is **no proof** for correctness. If you find a theoretical loophole in an MT program, you need to fix it.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. If multiple threads are contending for the same mutex then it is implementation specific which thread will get the mutex first. Multi-threaded programs should be written so that either the correctness is not dependent on which thread gets the mutex first or ordering is explicitly synchronised. It's not clear in your situation why you think it is a problem that some other thread gets the mutex first. The main thread will run after that thread unlocks the mutex.

Comment: @tofro Yes there is a theoretical loophole I think. But these functions are system calls. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You are using `pthread_cond_wait()` incorrectly. Read the manpage.

Comment: "*...thread2, locks the mutex first before pthread_cond_wait locks the mutex? The main thread is still blocked? If it does, then this program is a buggy program, all the threads(main thread and thread2) will be blocked.*" why would thread2 be blocked? It aquired the mutex, so it runs, and sooner or later will release the mutex and then the other thread would run again.